# UI hangs inspite calling a lengthy method in background thread

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading

I am calling a method like methodA in background.now if i call a lengthy method called methodB from methodA.should i separately mention it to be in background.the reason i ask this question is inspite of calling the lengthy process in background thread,the ui hangs for some time.

ie

```
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(methodA)];


    -(void)methodA
    {
     NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self methodB];
     [pool drain];
    }

     -(void)methodB
    {
     NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    //some lengthy process

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool drain];
    }
    -(void)updateTable
    {
     [self.tableview reloadData];
    }
```

is this way of calling background method right?

Comment: If methodB is only called from methodA, the NSAutoreleasePool in methodB might be excessive -- you're already covered by the one set up in methodA.

Comment: When you say the UI hangs, do you mean it becomes completely unresponsive and/or animations stop? More details please...

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with the above code. It's possible that the crux of the problem has been hidden by you posting simplified demo code rather the actual code. Can you post more of the actual code in question?

Comment: @occulus the ui becomes completely unresponsive..  well one more thing to ask...if the memory usage becomes too high (not enough to crash the app) will it make the app ui like this?

Comment: High memory usage on iOS won't have quite the same effects as on the desktop, because iOS doesn't page out memory to disk/storage the way a lot of desktop OSes do (which can cause apparent 'hanging' or freezes) -- so I wouldn't expect to see UI hangs due to low memory.
The most likely thing from what I can see is that something is indeed hogging the main thread. Can you post some actual real code at all? What is your time-consuming task actually doing? Is it doing something which is triggering processing on the main thread?

Comment: Also, are you sure your UITableViewDelegate and DataSource methods aren't also inadvertently doing something time-consuming as well?

Comment: To the commenters: there is almost no such thing as excessive NSAutoreleasePool, at least from a performance standpoint. (From a complexity standpoint, sure.) Mike Ash did some profiling.

Answer (score 1):

If a selector (method) X is called on a certain thread (whether it be background or main thread), any selectors that X calls (in the conventional fashion) are also on that same thread. So no, you don't need to call `performSelectorInBackground:` for each sub-call from `methodA:` as long as the entry-point selector is on the 'correct' thread, anything it then does is also on the 'correct' thread, including calls to other methods.

Note that the `NSAutoreleasePool` you set up in methodB looks unnecessary -- you don't really need it, since you're already inside the scope of the `NSAutoreleasePool` set up in `methodA`. (Assuming that `methodB` is only called from `methodA` as in the example!)

Incidently, have you put in `NSLogs` to absolutely verify that `//some lengthy process` is actually the thing taking all the time?

Comment: ya the lengthy process is iterations...i am looping some calculations about 100 times...which actually takes time...nothing involving ui is there in the calculations...